# in vue，how to pass values to children component when using component tag for dynamic switching component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How to pass values to children component when using component tag in vue ? It is seem that I cant't pass values to a child component using component tag unless using v-if:

```
<component :is="showNow"></component>
```

Comment: When data is passed to a subcomponent, it is passed through the prop.

Comment: All attributes will be passed to your dynamic component - thus all registered props will be parsed from attrs - you claim it is not working - can you show us your case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind prop object to dynamic component

```
const props = {
 customProp: 'foo'
}


<component :is="showNow" v-bind="props"></component>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass props dynamically, you can add the v-bind directive to your dynamic component and pass an object containing your prop names and values:

So your dynamic component would look like this:

```
<component :is="showNow" v-bind="currentProperties"></component>
```

And in your Vue instance, currentProperties can change based on the current component:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    currentComponent: 'showNow',
  }
},
computed: {
  currentProperties: function() {
    if (this.currentComponent === 'myComponent') {
      return { foo: 'bar' }
    }
  }
}
```

So now, when the currentComponent is myComponent, it will have a foo property equal to 'bar'. And when it isn't, no properties will be passed.